# is it possible recover the deleted docker image

Tags: docker

I execute the docker(`Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89`) clean command in the server:

```
docker system prune
```

to my surprise, this command delete the container that stopped. That's the problem, some container stopped by some reason but I still want to use it in the furture. Now it is deleted, is it possible to recover the mistaking deleted container that stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker images and containers are not the same. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46528745/6583529).

`docker system prune` tells you:

```
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

So it should be no surprise that it removed your container and possibly also the image it was based on (if no other container was running based on that same image).

I believe it is not possible to recover your image or container, however you can rebuild them. Depending on how the image was obtained you have to run:

```
docker pull <image> # for an image on dockerhub or other registry
docker build <arguments> # for an image based on a dockerfile
```

After that you will have your image and you can run a container again with:

```
docker run <image>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. You have to repull the image `docker pull image`, or  rebuild the image.